# How do I stop Windows RDP from appending a domain to my username?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, remote-desktop, aws-ssm, aws-session-manager

I've got a new corporate laptop and started running into this problem that I've never seen before.  I am using AWS Session Manager plugin to connect to an AWS EC2 Windows instance, although none of that is relevant.  The problem is that my username is being updated after I try to connect.

For example, I'll log in as "Administrator" but once I connect and it queries me for the password, it then fails and shows that I am logging in as "Administrator@xyz.com"  Since this is an AWS instance, it won't accept the username with my domain appended onto it.  How do I stop this?

Before and After screenshots attached

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lxQ5.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh7bD.png)

Answer (score 2):

A colleague helped me figure this out, so I'll post the answer in case it helps someone else.  The trick is to put the following value into the Username field:

"ec2_ip_address\username"

For example, if my instance's IP address was 10.0.1.5 and my account on the instance was "Administrator", my username value would be "10.0.1.5\Administrator".  The domain is no longer appended!

Hope this helps someone else!